# Passing Google Analytics Tracking info via forms

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Lets say I have a customer who comes into my website through a google analytics tagged link (with utm_campaign, utm_source, utm_medium etc added).

They click around the site on a few different pages, then fill in a form.  The utm_ values no longer show in the URL on the form page.

Is there any way for me to get those values (utm_campaign, utm_source, utm_medium) so I can populate hidden fields in my form, and track the campaign source of these leads in my CRM?  Can I use JavaScript to read the Google Analytics cookie to extract these?

We have a large website with thousands of products and dozens of forms, so something that I can implement on the forms would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to extract campaign info from cookies in Google Analytics Classic. From Google Analytics Universal onwards it is no longer possible, so an idea is to create a cookie yourself where to save that information as soon as the user lands on the entry page.